# Failed to find Build Tools revision 34.0.0

Tags: macos, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

I downloaded Android SDK Build-tools for Android Studio (Mac version). But the `Android SDK Build-Tools 34` doesn't install like this photo:

[image]

You can see the build-tools folder exists in the Android SDK path.

So I set environment variables in .zshrc and .bash_profile like this:

```
# Setting PATH for flutter
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/frontdeveloper/development/flutter/bin"

# Setting PATH for java
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

# Setting PATH for Android
export ANDROID_HOME="/Users/frontdeveloper/Library/Android/sdk"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH"
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH"export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Help me, please!